# Mongodb connection error whenever rebooting server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using aws and installed ubuntu server on aws ec2.
I installed mongodb on it.
When installing mongodb, it is working well.
But If i reboot server and try to connect mongod in termina. I am getting the following error.

**MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:362:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1**

So whenever reboot server, i have to execute the following command and then mongo is working again.
sudo systemctl stop mongod
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
sudo mongod --fork --logpath /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.log --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
sudo systemctl start mongod

I think whenever reboot server, executing above command does not make sense.
If anyone have experienced, please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you setup the `mongodb` you usually would `enable` it, so that it starts after each reboot:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Comment: Now it is working. Anyhow your answer helped me for future setup.

Comment: @BaiMaoli Glad to hear that :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can we go to private chat? I need still more help reguard for mongo db.

Comment: @BaiMaoli No problem. If there is a new issue, you could make new question if you want.

Comment: SO chat could be better: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219387/test